# Easy way to download IMAP mails to client

Tags: email, imap

We are changing our mail servers to Google Apps. Most of our cilents use POP and have no issues. But one is using webmail-only and has years of mails stored on our server. They do not mind NOT migrating this to Google Apps, but they DO want a copy of those mails. But I can not find a tool to provide to this client to download his mail.

He could install an e-mail client and download it using POP, but this would only work for RECEIVED mails. And the SENT mails are just as important. Importing into Google Apps is only possible with the paid version. The only thing I can come up with is installing this as IMAP and then dragging all folders to local folders. But this is cumbersome and for a non-tech client not very convenient. Are there other options or tools?

Server is using cPanel and Maildir format for storing mails.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might take a look here:

http://migrationtool.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It took some tweaking of this script to make it work with PHP5.3 and Gmail, but it ultimately allowed me to transfer all mail... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer will most likely lie in the mail client he's using. For instance, Outlook offers a way to export mail folders to a file (.pfx) which can be imported at a later date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [offlineimap](http://jgoerzen.github.com/offlineimap/manual.html) to mirror existing email boxes between a Maildir format on your local host, or configure it to mirror two existing imap servers directly (see the manual). It offers a special front-end for Gmail box types, as well.